# The computer after motherboard replacement turns on and off continually

Tags: motherboard

First of all I would like to stress I'm beginner and probably I'm not doing something right. 
I replaced my old motherboard (AK35S20C Schuttle) with a new motherboard (Soltek SL-75DRV75).

Unfortunately the replacement isn't working as expected.

Symptoms are:
The computer powers on, works less than a second and powers off. Then it powers on again and so on. It doesn't emit any sound, it looks like it resets very quickly.

Do you have any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: My suggestion is that you Google "What to do if my computer won't turn on" and follow some of the troubleshooting guides you will find there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my old MSI board. I assumed it was due to a fissure on the board since it sometimes worked when I gently jogged at the RAM modules, PCI cards and such stuff.

Maybe in your case just check that everything's plugged in correctly and that connector pins aren't bended.

Also ensure that your PSU has enough power.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your motherboard supports your processor and that you set FSB correctly.

Shuttle  AK35S20C uses VIA KT333 chipset while Soltek uses VIA KT266 chipset, as far as I can find out. Unfortunately, Soltek died, so I can't get any official information about it.

It could also be that your new motherboard (which is older than old motherboard) doesn't support your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

When a machine does this, in my experience it is either down to lack of power or some hardware component is inserted incorrectly.

I have seen this (computer repeatedly turns on and off) when the CPU is missing.